# How to disable 'This workbooks contains one or more links that cannot be updated' popup on open

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

When opening a sheet I get this popup, how to suppress it completely on sheet basis, not machine basis? I never want to see it no matter whats the status of the links.

[image]

Comment: have you tried going to "edit links..." and disable asking for updates, or even breaking the links?

Comment: What version of Excel are you running?

Comment: yes I did it for every link, but I need those links @MátéJuhász

Comment: @Reeves version 2010

Comment: It looks like this has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908372/how-to-suppress-update-links-warning - Please delete your question if this works for you.